# Stretched layout vs flowing layout

Tags: oracle-adf

I was reading on [Oracle ADF Faces documentation](http://rcf.us.oracle.com:9008/faces-12.1.3.0.0/faces/feature/layoutBasics.jspx) for guidelines regarding layouts. At a higher level it mentions these as best practices for creating robust layouts that works consistently across all browsers:

1. Create a stretchable outer frame
2. Create flowing islands

What is the difference between stretching layouts  and flowing/scrolling layouts? Can some one can provide an appropriate example.

Answer (score 3):

A seminar about the topic is here: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/layouts/layouts.html

Stretch layout adjusts to fill the browser regardless of the browser window size adding scrollbars as needed.
Flow layout don't stretch and are kept fixed.

Comment: why are flow layouts called so?

Answer (score 2):

Stretchable outer frame to fit the whole browser window, in order to take the whole space and make use of the whole browser windows without adding any scrollbars to the page itself, but internal scroll bar can exist for tables inside the outer frame.

One article I could find in here -> http://www.jobinesh.com/2010/03/adf-faces-layout-tips.html can tell you more about stretchable layouts in ADF, a little bit old but still so much valid.